# CTCallCenter crash

Tags: ios, phone-call, core-telephony

I am developing an iPhone application that has to synchronize with phone call statuses. I am currently playing audio and/or communicating with an external accessory so my application can run in background. So when there is a phone call i show a view telling the user that a phone call is taking place. I am using the CTCallCenter (using an instance variable in my appDelegate) to respond to phone call statuses and i am allocating that instance every time i test if there is a phone call or not. Bur when allocating that instance each time , sometimes i get a strange crash concerning "CUTWeakReference" class. i want to know if there is a best practice for using CTCallCenter when application is in background or is suspended to prevent that crash from happening ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Points to consider to fix the issue.**

There is an iOS bug that causes instances of the `CTCallCenter` class to sometimes get notifications after they have been deallocated. Instead of instantiating, using, and releasing instances you must instead retain and never release them to work around the bug.

The `[[CTCallCenter alloc] init]` must be run in the main queue. Is it thread safe ??? Better call it on main thread only.

```
static CTCallCenter *netInfo; static dispatch_once_t dispatchToken; 
if (!netInfo) {
    dispatch_once(&dispatchToken, ^{ 
        netInfo = [[CTCallCenter alloc] init]; 
    }); 
}
```